# web3js encodeABI() is there way to call it asynchronously?

Tags: web3js

I am working on an ERC827 contract invocation through metamask. For ERC827 transfer method require an additional 'data' argument. Since encodeABI()supports only synchronous invocation, metamask throws error. Is there a way to workaround this problem?

my contract invocation code is something like below.

```
let erc827_abi = { contract abi}
let service_abi = {contract abi}
var erc827_address = '0x9df5e31a1e5de828254d535d5c9b514d513316e8'
var service_crt_address = '0x1ce94a12f58b0b9b39d0a9f1520878a07d9a72e8' 
var user_address = web3.eth.accounts[0]

const erc827contractInstance = web3.eth.contract(erc827_abi).at(erc827_address);
const servicecontractInstance = web3.eth.contract(service_abi).at(service_crt_address);

//encodeABI() is the call which fails.

const sdata = servicecontractInstance.bookService(args.servicename,user_address,args.customername,args.servicetype,args.value,args.transaction_type,args.account_number).encodeABI(function(error, result){
 if(!error)
     console.log(result);
 else
     console.error(error)
 });
console.log("encoded ABI is",sdata)


erc827contractInstance.transferFrom(user_address,testadd_2,tokensToSend,sdata{from: testadd_2,gas:55000},function (error, result){ //get callback from function which is your transaction key
   if(!error){
        console.log(result);
    } else{
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

if encodeABI() is invoked like below it works.

```
const sdata = servicecontractInstance.bookService(args.servicename,user_address,args.customername,args.servicetype,args.value,args.transaction_type,args.account_number).encodeABI();
```

But unfortunately metamask does not support this.

appreciate any pointers on resolving this.

Thanks James for your response. Please see the error information. not sure this is the one you are looking for.

```
inpage.js:1 Uncaught Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_sendTransaction without a callback parameter. See https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dizzy-all-async---think-of-metamask-as-a-light-client for details.
    at MetamaskInpageProvider.send (inpage.js:1)
    at s.send (inpage.js:1)
    at n.e [as sendTransaction] (inpage.js:1)
    at u.sendTransaction (inpage.js:1)
    at u.execute (inpage.js:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (:formatted:1767)
MetamaskInpageProvider.send @ inpage.js:1
s.send @ inpage.js:1
e @ inpage.js:1
u.sendTransaction @ inpage.js:1
u.execute @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ :formatted:1767
```

Comment: Could you provide a stack trace?

Comment: I *think* the problem is that you're calling `contract.myMethod(params).encodeABI()`, rather than `contract.myMethod.encodeABI(params)`, but I'll need to double-check. Also, it looks like you're using the Web3 instance injected by MetaMask. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

In Web3 0.20 (which, if you're using the Web3 injected by MetaMask, is what you're using - BTW, don't do that), `myContract.myMethod(params)` will *make a transaction with those parameters*. Then `myContract.myMethod(params).encodeABI()` would attempt to call `encodeABI` on the result of that transaction, which is probably not what you want, not least because `encodeABI` doesn't exist in Web3 0.20.

In Web3 0.20, the equivalent encantation would be `myContract.myMethod.getData(params)`.

Comment: In web3 v0.20 `.encodeABI()` was named [`.getData()`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods).

Comment: 'don't do that' why?

Comment: MetaMask themselves recommend against using the bundled Web3: https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md. Historically, Web3 has had breaking changes from one release to the next, and it means the code you're running is different to the code you've tested. They've deprecated the bundled Web3 instance, and plan to remove it soon - indeed Mist (an alternative to MetaMask) already has.

Comment: Thanks James and Ismael. James, as you suggested myContract.myMethod.getData(params) works. I am relatively new to this. So your suggestion is use own instance of web3 or other libraries other than the injected one?

Comment: Yes, that is generally the best approach. If you want to stick with Web3 0.20, use the instructions at https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#adding-web3. Most alternative libraries will have similar instructions in their "Getting Started" section.